# Why isn't chdir happening for this rc.d script?

Tags: freebsd, rc, rc.d

I've hit a wall trying to understand why the `${name}_chdir` variable is not working for me.  Finally, after letting my script run with `-xv`, I see that the **cd** command is not even being run in my case.  Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -xv
exec 1>/tmp/awning.rclog 2>&1

# REQUIRE: NETWORKING LOGIN DAEMON
# KEYWORD: shutdown

. /etc/rc.subr

name="awning"
rcvar="awning_enable"
awning_chdir="/usr/sbin/awning"

pidfile="/var/run/awningd.pid"
procname="daemon"

# -f flag is to redirect stdin/stdout/stderr to /dev/null to prevent node from crashing
# on system-startup
start_cmd="/usr/sbin/daemon -r -P ${pidfile} -f -u pierre /usr/sbin/awning/intro.js"
command="/usr/sbin/daemon -r -P ${pidfile} -f -u pierre /usr/sbin/awning/intro.js"
load_rc_config $name
run_rc_command "$1"
```

At first I was only using `start_cmd`, but then I read in [rc.subr](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rc.subr&sektion=8) the following:

> ${name}_chdir
>
> ```
>         Directory to cd to before running _command_, if
>         ${name}_chroot is not provided.
> ```

so I thought maybe things were getting mixed up, so i added the `command=....` bit, and removed the `start_cmd=....` line, and still no success.  Here's the relevant "doit" portion of the output which was saved from running the script with `-xv`:

```
+ _chdir=/usr/sbin/awning _chroot='' _nice='' _user='' _group='' _groups='' _fib='' _env='' _prepend='' _login_class=daemon _oomprotect=''
+ [ -n '' ]
+ [ -z yes ]
+ [ start '!=' start ]
+ [ -n awning_enable -a start '!=' rcvar -a start '!=' stop -a start '!=' describe ]
+ checkyesno awning_enable
+ eval '_value=$awning_enable'
+ _value=YES
+ debug 'checkyesno: awning_enable is set to YES.'
+ return 0
+ [ start '=' start -a -z yes -a -n '' ]
+ eval '_cmd=$start_cmd' '_precmd=$start_precmd' '_postcmd=$start_postcmd'
+ _cmd='/usr/sbin/daemon -r -P /var/run/awningd.pid -f -u pierre /usr/sbin/awning/intro.js' _precmd='' _postcmd=''
+ [ -n '/usr/sbin/daemon -r -P /var/run/awningd.pid -f -u pierre /usr/sbin/awning/intro.js' ]
+ _run_rc_precmd
+ check_required_before start
+ local _f
+ return 0
+ [ -n '' ]
+ check_required_after start
+ local _f _args
+ return 0
+ return 0
+ _run_rc_doit '/usr/sbin/daemon -r -P /var/run/awningd.pid -f -u pierre /usr/sbin/awning/intro.js '
+ debug 'run_rc_command: doit: /usr/sbin/daemon -r -P /var/run/awningd.pid -f -u pierre /usr/sbin/awning/intro.js '
+ eval '/usr/sbin/daemon -r -P /var/run/awningd.pid -f -u pierre /usr/sbin/awning/intro.js '
+ /usr/sbin/daemon -r -P /var/run/awningd.pid -f -u pierre /usr/sbin/awning/intro.js
+ _return=0
+ [ 0 -ne 0 ]
+ return 0
+ _run_rc_postcmd
+ [ -n '' ]
+ return 0
+ return 0
```

`_chdir` is being set properly, but it's never used for anything.  Honestly it looks like those variables (`_chdir`, `_chroot`, etc) should actually be `awning_chdir`, `awning_chroot`, etc...

What could be going on?

I'm running version 11.0-RELEASE-p2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After stepping through */etc/rc.subr*, I learned (the hard way) that **command=** needs to literally be a single command.  There's a test done on it (`[ ! -x $command ]`) which fails even for a command with options and no arguments.  I had to split apart the options I was passing `daemon`, and its single argument `/usr/sbin/awning/intro.js` into a separate variable: **command_args=**, which solved the issue.